# Do Firebase Storage security rules support version 2?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-language?hl=en&authuser=0#cloud-storage

In the above documentation, it seems to suggest that Storage security rules support version 2 but none of the Storage examples opt into version 2, only the Firestore rules do. Do Storage security rules support version 2?

Also, in my Firestore rules, which opt into version 2, I only grant read and write access to admins up front and any rules subsequent to that are for non-admin access, and it works fine.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        function isAdmin() {
            return request.auth.token.admin == true;
        }

        function isSignedIn() {
            return request.auth != null;
        }

        match /{doc=**} {
            allow write: if isAdmin();
            allow read: if isAdmin();
        }

        // THIS IS EVALUATED FOR NON-ADMIN USERS 
        match /someCollection/{doc} {
            allow read: if isSignedIn();
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I use this pattern this with Storage rules, it appears that after the admin check is evaluated, the task returns and ignores the rest of the conditions, thereby blocking all read and write access for non-admin users.

```
service firebase.storage {
    match /b/{bucket}/o {
        function isAdmin() {
            return request.auth.token.admin == true;
        }

        function isSignedIn() {
            return request.auth != null;
        }

        match /{allPaths=**} {
            allow write: if isAdmin();
            allow read: if isAdmin();
        }

        // THIS IS NOT EVALUATED FOR NON-ADMIN USERS 
        match /images/fruits/{allPaths=**} {
            allow read;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a feature of version 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly, version 2 of Firebase security rules for Cloud Storage was introduced to support securing list operations, so unless you use those the version number is likely to make little difference.

My guess is that the other rules snippets in the documentation simply haven't been updated to specify a version, since they work the same on either of them.